# Sequelize ORM, Hooks not working with associations

Tags: associations, sequelize.js, hook

I have 2 models a Department and a Staff and they are associated through a belongsToMany association.

Now I need to call a function whenever staff.addDepartment is called. 
I'm trying to use hooks and the sequelize documentation states that "When using add/set functions the beforeUpdate/afterUpdate hooks will run."

[image]

But after some time trying to make it work the hook 'afterUpdate' is still not being called when addDepartment is called

**Staff Model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const Staff = sequelize.define('Staff', {          
        workingLocation: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: true,
        },           
      },
      {
        freezeTableName: true,
        hooks: {
          afterCreate: (instance, options) => {
            console.log('\n\n\nSTAFF -> Hook associting staff to department: \n\n\n', staffDepartment);
          },            
          beforeUpdate: (instance, options) => {
            console.log('\n\n\n Before update model \n\n\n', staffDepartment);
          },
          afterUpdate: (instance, options) => {
            console.log('\n\n\nAfter update model \n\n\n', staffDepartment);
          },
        },
      }
      );

        Staff.associate = (models) => {

          Staff.belongsTo(
            models.Person,
            {
              foreignKey: {
                allowNull: false,
              },
              onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            }
          );


          Staff.belongsToMany(models.Department,
            {
              through: 'StaffDepartment',
              onDelete: 'CASCADE',
              onUpdate: 'CASCADE',                 
            }
          );
        };

      return Staff;
    };
```

**Department Model**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Department = sequelize.define('Department', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    acronym: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  {
    freezeTableName: true,
    hooks: {
      afterCreate: (staffDepartment, options) => {
        console.log('\n\n\Department -> Hook associting staff to department: \n\n\n', staffDepartment);
      },         
      beforeUpdate: (staffDepartment, options) => {
        console.log('\n\n\n Department Before update model \n\n\n', staffDepartment);
      },
      afterUpdate: (staffDepartment, options) => {
        console.log('\n\n\n Department After update model \n\n\n', staffDepartment);
      },
    },
  }
  );

  Department.associate = (models) => {         
    Department.belongsToMany(models.Staff,
        {
          through: 'StaffDepartment',
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
          onUpdate: 'CASCADE',             
        }
      );

    Department.hasMany(models.Course,
      {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      }
    );
  };

  return Department;
};
```

**Code that I wish triggered the hook afterUpdate on the Staff Model**

```
  Staff.findById(staff.id).then((s) => {                  
                s.addDepartment(departmentId);                
            });
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Shouldn't you be expecting `afterCreate` and not `afterUpdate`?

Comment: When I call s.addDepartmento() the staff has already been created, so the afterCreate hook triggers in the moment that staff is created and not in the moment where a department is added to staff. 
I wanted a hook that was triggered when you add an association object...

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution? I am in a similar situation and would benefit from your knowledge if you know the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is facing this issue, what worked for me is configuring `belongsToMany` associations with a model.

In your case it would be `{ through: StaffDepartment, hooks: true }` instead of configuring it with a simple string literal in `{ through: 'StaffDepartment', hooks: true }`

And in your StaffDepartment.js:

```js
hooks: {
  afterBulkCreate: (instance, options) => {
          
  }
}
```

As a sidenote, what worked in my use case were `afterBulkCreate` and `afterBulkDestroy` since here we are interacting with the association model not the models themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem but found a solution. When you make a association between tables you have to use the `afterBulkUpdate` if you want to run a hook before update a record.